# How to dynamically allow users in OpenSSH?

Tags: openssh, libssh

I want to be able to block or allow users based on the result of an external script using OpenSSH. I see that `libssh` has [support for callbacks](http://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__callbacks.html#gaa321f33172cfa54eb50baaa963457a17), but after reading the OpenSSH man pages I cannot find anywhere that this functionality is handed to the user.

For example, I'd like to be able to maintain either a file or even an API that contains a username blacklist or whitelist, and have OpenSSH consult these lists during the authentication process.

Ideas I've had so far, and why they are insufficient:

1. **Make use of `sshd_config`: `AllowUsers`.** This is a start, but since it does not read from a file, it is not dynamic. The configuration file would need to be changed every time and the service restarted. Additionally, modifying the config file from a script is dangerous and terrible.
2. **Make use of `sshd_config`: `AuthorizedKeysCommand`.** Unfortunately, while this does allow  you to specify a script and grant access based on the result, it does not allow denial of access. If the script returns nothing, `sshd` continues to try other methods of authentication.
3. Recompile OpenSSH with an addition that implements the `libssh` callbacks. I'd rather not do this for obvious reasons of maintainability.

Is there another method that I have missed while reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

For 2. you could limit authentication to *publickey* with [AuthenticationMethods](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthenticationMethods).

Another option is to use PAM and implement your own PAM authz module.

Comment: Thanks, limiting to publickey auth did not block it because it would still check authorized_keys. I ended up disabling that. PAM would also be a valid way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is sufficient if you disable checking authorized_keys:

sshd_config:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /etc/ssh/my-custom-command
AuthorizedKeysUser nobody
AuthorizedKeysFile none
```

my-custom-command:

```
# $1 is user, as passed from sshd

#psuedo code:
if $1 is in whitelist:
cat /home/$1/.ssh/authorized_keys
exit 0
else
exit 1
```